# Exception when trying to use DynamoDBMapper: no mapping for HASH key

Tags: database, hash, nosql, amazon-dynamodb, primary-key

I have a DynamoDB table with a primary key (id : integer) and secondary key (dateTo : String). I've made a Class that utilizes DynamoDBMapper:

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName="MyItems"
public class MyItemsMapper {
    private int id;
    private String dateTo;
    private String name;

    @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName="id")
    public void setId(int id) { this.id = id; }
    public int getId() { return id; }

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName="dateTo")
    public void setDateTo(String dateTo) { this.dateTo = dateTo; }
    public String getDateTo() { return dateTo; }

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName="name")
    public void setName(String name { this.name = name; }
    public String getName() { return name; }

    public boolean saveItem(MyItemsMapper item) {
      try {
        DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(client); //<-- This connects to the DB. This works fine.
        item.setId(generateUniqueNumber()); //<-- This generates a unique integer. Also seems to work fine.
        mapper.save(item);
        logger.info("Successfully saved item. See info below.");
        logger.info(item.toString());
        return true;
      } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Exception while trying to save item: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
      }
    }
}
```

I then have a manager class that uses the bean above, like so:

```
public class MyManager {
    public boolean recordItem(
            int id,
            String dateTo,
            String name,
    ) {
        MyItemsMapper myItemsMapper = new MyItemsMapper();
        myItemsMapper.setId(id);
        myItemsMapper.setDateTo(dateTo);
        myItemsMapper.setName(name);
        myItemsMapper.saveItem(myItemsMapper);
    }
}
```

I am running the manager class in a JUnit test:

```
public class MyManagerTest {
    @Test
    public void saveNewItemTest() {
        MyManager myManager = new MyManager();
        myManager.recordItem(1234567, "2018-01-01", "Anthony");
    }
}
```

When I use the `saveItem` method above via my manager by running my JUnit test, I get the following error:

```
com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMappingException: MyItemsMapper; no mapping for HASH key
```

Not really sure what it's pertaining to, as I definitely have a primary key for my table and my secondary key always has a value as well.

How do I get this to work?

**More Info:**

It's worth noting that I can record data into my DynamoDB table via the `Item object`. If I do the below, my data gets recorded into the database:

```
DynamoDB dynamoDB = new DynamoDBClient().connectToDynamoDB(); //<-- 
Connection. Works fine.
Table table = dynamoDB.getTable("MyItems");
item.withPrimaryKey("id", 1234567);
item.withString("dateTo", "2018-01-01");
item.withString("name", "Anthony");
PutItemOutcome outcome = table.putItem(item);
```

However, I'm trying to use DynamoDBMapper because I'm reading that it is a more organized, better way to access data.

Comment: Im not quite sure what you are trying to achieve in this code. You have some kind of mapping object called MyItemsMapper but it doesn't appear to be used. Can you describe your approach?

You pass in a VendorAlertsMapper object and save that, so we would really need to see that code to see why its failing.

Comment: @Stu Updated original post with more code and information.

Comment: `VendorAlertsMapper` should have really been `MyItemsMapper`.

Comment: Can you confirm what data type your partition key is? Go into the Dynamo Console, in the Tables view there is a table with columns Name, Status, Partition Key... Can you copy the value from partition key? For example I have table with this "userId (String)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure if this is causing the problem, but you are creating the myItemsMapper object, then passing a reference to this object to itself.

I would suggest removing your saveItem method. The MyItemsMapper class should be a plain old java object. Then make MyManager like this

```
public class MyManager {
    public boolean recordItem(
            int id,
            String dateTo,
            String name,
    ) {
        MyItemsMapper myItemsMapper = new MyItemsMapper();
        myItemsMapper.setId(id);
        myItemsMapper.setDateTo(dateTo);
        myItemsMapper.setName(name);
        DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(client); 
        mapper.save(myItemsMapper);
    }
}
```

If you particularly want to keep the saveItem method make it like this

```
public boolean saveItem() {
  try {
    DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(client);
    mapper.save(this);
    logger.info("Successfully saved item. See info below.");
    logger.info(this.toString());
    return true;
  } catch (Exception e) {
    logger.error("Exception while trying to save item: " + e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
    return false;
  }
}
```

And then in MyManager do

```
    MyItemsMapper myItemsMapper = new MyItemsMapper();
    myItemsMapper.setId(id);
    myItemsMapper.setDateTo(dateTo);
    myItemsMapper.setName(name);
    myItemsMapper.saveItem();
```